In $\iint_Dy\;dxdy$, why do we draw horizontal arrows for $dxdy$ and vertical arrows for $dydx$?
I was studying the double integrals from a video lecture. This is a problem from the video:

Evaluate the following integral. $D$ represents the region enclosed by
$y=\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and the $x$-axis.
$$\iint_Dy\;dxdy$$

The lecturer says that the most important thing for evaluating this integral is to determine the limits of the integrals. First, we draw the graph of the region $D$. He goes on to say that we can evaluate the integral in two ways: We can either have $dxdy$ or $dydx$ but the limits for each are determined as follows:
If $dx$ comes first, we draw a horizontal arrow in the graph:

So according to the graph, $x$ changes from $-\sqrt{9-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{9-y^2}$ and $y$ changes from $0$ to $3$. So the integral is:
$$\int_0^3\int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}y\;dxdy$$
If $dy$ comes first, we should draw a vertical arrow in the graph:

According to the graph, $y$ changes from $0$ to $\sqrt{9-x^2}$ and $x$ changes from $-3$ to $3$. The integral is
$$\int_{-3}^3\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-x^2}}y \;dydx$$

I want to understand why we do this process for determining integral limits? Specifically, I'm wondering why we draw horizontal arrows if $dx$ comes first, and why the vertical arrows when $dy$ comes first?


For the graph above, let's first compute the area of the purple surface at $x=x_0$, which is $$\int_{y_1(x_0)}^{y_2(x_0)}f(x_0,y)dy$$
Now, for any $x\in [a,b]$, the surface area is $$A(x)=\int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)}f(x,y)dy$$
Finally, we add all these surface areas from $a$ to $b$, i.e. $$\int_a^bA(x)dx=\int_a^b\int_{y_1(x)}^{y_2(x)}f(x,y)dydx$$

Thanks for the answer! Your answer along with this tutorial about the double integration, gave me the intuition of what is going on when we change $dxdy$ to $dydx$.

Let's say you want to compute
$$\int_D f(x,y) \ \text dA$$
We can write this as an iterated integral in many ways, but the two ways we're considering are to use $\text dA = \text dx \text dy$ or $\text dA = \text dy \text dx$. How do we determine the limits of integration in each case? Let's write one of these out in general:
$$ \int_c^d\left( \int_a^b f(x,y) \ \text dx\right)\text dy$$
The outer integral says to break up the $y$-axis into little pieces, and on each little piece, calculate the value of the inner integral. So, when we're in the inner integral, we have a fixed $y$ value already. Now, given that fixed $y$, what are the bounds on the $x$-axis? A fixed $y$ value is a horizontal line, so draw a horizontal line (or arrow) and see which interval of $x$ values represents being in $D$, which is $(a,b)$. Depending on the shape of $D$, $a$ and/or $b$ may depend on that fixed $y$ value.
When you change the order of integration, the whole situation flips. We have the outer integral with respect to $x$, so we fix $x$ (which gives us vertical lines/arrows) and determine the $y$ interval (possibly in terms of the fixed $x$).
